# No video with supported format and mime type in my php code

Tags: html, video, webserver, server, video-player

alert('Your Comment is added!')";

    }

     else{



         echo "alert('Cannot Comment')";



         } 



    }

    ?>

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="description" content="" >

<meta name="author" content="">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Compaign Shack </title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/fevicon.png"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1
```

/jquery.min.js">

```
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4
```

/js/bootstrap.min.js">

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<style>

#comment{

border-bottom-left-radius:5px;


border-bottom-right-radius:5px;

border-top-left-radius:5px;

border-top-right-radius:5px;

box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
```

}

```
<div class="container">
```

**Advetising Agency :** 
**".$agency." , Brand Name : ".$row['br_name']."**"; ?>

                        

                         Television

Image

Outdoor

Print

Digital

radio

";








      ?>                   







                        

                

                

                    


                        

                        

                        '>



                            

                        " type="video/mp4">

                        " type="video/ogg">

                        " type="video/webm">

                                                



                    





                        

                        







                        

                         " 
style='width:60%; height:60%'>


                        





                        

                        



                        

                         " 
style='width:60%; height:60%'>

                        

                        

                        



                        

                         " 
style='width:60%; height:60%'>

                        


                        

                        


                        

                     " style='width:60%; 
height:60%'>


                        

                        

                        



                        

                         " 
style='width:60%; height:60%'>

```
</div>
```

Other Details

Other Details :

 "; ?> 






Creative Team       : **$cr**           

";

echo "Month         :  **$row[month]**

";

echo "Advertising Agency         :  
**$row[ad_agency]**
";

echo "Account Team  : $a_t    
";

echo "Brand Name         :  ".$b_name." 

Campaign Slogan    :  ".$c_slo ."

Media Release      :  ".$m_r   ." 

Account Leader     :  " . $a_l    ."

Production         :    ". $pr    ." 

Research Agency    :  ". $r_a  ."  

Additional Credit  :  ". $a_c."

Media  :  TV,Radio,Outdoor,Digital,Print 

 ";

}

?>





            

                

                    


                        


                        




                    

                    

                        2014-03-06 7:37 am

hallo, please help me, i get invalid 

article id, i already follow all the instruction and no such 

`php?id=1` at my page, im using phpadmin v 5.1,

without article id, nothing i can progress. tq

-->

Wanna Comment ?? Login here";       

}

else{

    echo "

    


    


    


    






            
    ";

    }

?>




            

                

                    


                        ";


                        echo ''.$rrrr[3].'';




                    echo "


                    


                        2014-03-06 7:37 am";


                               echo  "".$rrrr[2]."

";

                               $na=$rrrr[3];

                               if($na==$una){


                        echo "";

                               }

                    echo "          

                    

                

            

        ";








}


/*


echo "";


$qqq="select * from comment where post_id=".$_GET['id'];

$rrr=mysqli_query($con,$qqq);

while($rrrr=mysqli_fetch_array($rrr))

{

$na=$rrrr[3];

echo "



$rrrr[3]

$rrrr[2]

";

if($una==$na){



echo " delete

";}

else{

 echo "";

}


echo "



";


}


?>





 */

 ?>

|  Login

                        


                           
|  Register

                        



                             



                

                    

                      Campaign Shack News 

                    


                                


                            Have you ever stumbled across a Pakistani advertisement and 

wondered about the people and agencies behind the advertising campaign? The 

creative minds who have attempted to communicate some brand related message to 

you? 
                                Or about the ad work that was done in a 

particular time frame?

                                Have you ever stumbled across a Pakistani advertisement and wondered 

about the people and agencies behind the advertising campaign? The creative 

minds who have attempted to communicate some brand related message to you? 


                                Or about the ad work that was done in a 

particular time frame?



                            

                

                

                        

                        Space for Google Adds

```
</div>
```

```
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>




<div id="picture_view" class="modal fade">

<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">

            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
```

aria-hidden="true">×

```
            <h4 class="modal-title">View</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

         <img src='img/1.png '/>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
```

data-dismiss="modal">Close

```
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

When i upload a video individually from FTP it will play and when i'll upload form a website it show the mime type or something remove type error

Here is the Link:
http://campaignshack.com/subarchives.php?id=85

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` You have some syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you see the semi-colon in

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);{
                             ^ right there
```

that is killing your script and tells it to end the statement.

Nothing in there will executed.

Remove it.

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($res){
```

However, that should be a `while` loop.

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){...}
```

as in:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

    $img1=$row['image'];

    $video=$row['video'];

    $show="/vdo/".$video;

    $lom=$row['lo_med'];

    $agency=$row['ad_agency'];

}
```

---

Also make sure that `$_GET['id']` is indeed an `int` and not a string.

Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

If it is a string, then you will need to modify your query, such as:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$query="select * from archives where id='".$id."'";
```

But this method is open [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/),  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: after removing the semicolon it says 500 internal server error

Comment: @SheikhNomanMehmood You may not have seen an additional edit I've made. Please reload my answer where I've mentioned about using a `while` loop. Plus, check your logs and use error reporting as stated at the bottom of my answer. Plus, the error may be coming from elsewhere in code you're not showing us.

Comment: i use while loop as you suggest me and the second thing is error reporting when i set error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); it shows 500 - internal server error

Comment: When i use cyberduck and upload any video/image individually from ftp connection it play and when i'll upload from website it shows mime type errors and in image box a thumbnail will be occurred rather than image

Comment: @SheikhNomanMehmood the problem lies elsewhere then. This isn't a MySQL or PHP error, it's a server error. You need to post more or full code.

Comment: fine for a while its a server error then what is the solution dear if it was server error kindly suggest me solution because i have to submit the site

Comment: @SheikhNomanMehmood That is out of scope of the question and should be posted on Stack's server fault section. Either that, or check with your hosting provider where they may have error logs you can look into.

Comment: @SheikhNomanMehmood Sure thanks, but that is just way too much code. Plus, you should be making an edit under your original post, rather than overwriting your original question while using the code I told you to replace with. People will see the question and my answer and ask themselves: *"The loop is there, so why the answer?"*, in turn possibly downvoting my answer for it. Plus, this doesn't help `error_reporting(0);` it means do NOT show errors. Again, the problem may very well not be in your posted code, but on the SERVER.